How I can move route founded in routes\auth.php to routes\api.php?
routes\auth.php
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.store');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('verify-email', EmailVerificationPromptController::class)
                ->name('verification.notice');

    Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', VerifyEmailController::class)
                ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');

    Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
                ->name('verification.send');

    Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
                ->name('password.confirm');

    Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

    Route::put('password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])->name('password.update');

    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->name('logout');
});

routes\api.php
Route::middleware('languages')->prefix('{locale}')->where(['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'])
     ->group(function(){
    
});

I tried to localize my web application and I installed breeze auth, how I route auth.php in routes api.php using Laravel 11? any advice**.**
Does it affect the authentication breeze?

There should have been an option to select "API" when installing laravel breeze though.

Yes, but I choose a blade.

So.... you want to use blade while your login/logout (auth routes) are from api (accessible via ajax/axios/xhr)?

what you have on your RouteServiceProvider in boot()?

@francisco Paginator::useBootstrap();

@Mr.Kenneth No, I did not use ajax/axios/xhr

have you try passe all code from one side to the other?  in RouteServiceProvider  you can change to like: Route::prefix('api')->middleware('api')->group(base_path('routes/auth.php'));

@francisco RouteServiceProvider is not available.

@francisco I try it in bootstrap/app.php, but page not found. I use this route http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/en/login

I am pretty sure you will have to change logic in the controllers a bit if you will have only APIes. If you will have standard web app and some APIes then you will have to create something like APILoginController and make the logic which will handle token generation and other parts of the login. If you need more infos, reach out :)
